# How to remove microcode firmware for intel cpus from intel-microcode

Tags: wireless

[image]

How to remove microcode firmware for intel cpus from `intel-microcode` because of that i cant use the wifi on my laptop. Pls help for activating wifi. I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Sorry?! You are really making a mess of this:  what does the microcode firmware (it is for your CPU) have to do with your wifi?  Next: it is NOT installed so why would you need to remove it? Next: if you want your wifi working please provide the required information we need to advice you.

Comment: No, it´s unrelated except in a very few cases of INTEL WiFi cards and is actually the opposite of what you mentioned, i.e., the Intel microcode IS required. But yours isn't installed and you have a Broadcom. I advise you not to get into the X-Y trap: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @CelticWarrior Intel microcode is not related to Intel WiFi cards at all.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Until recently I would have agreed but there was one or a couple of questions here where Chili555 found otherwise after extensive troubleshooting. No, I'm not making an *argument from authority* but it happens that I trust Dr. Chili a lot. However, I still think of it as quite not plausible but regardless of its validity, it has nothing to do with this case, a textbook example of the X-Y problem mentioned above.

Comment: @CelticWarrior My recent case involving intel-microcode was a severely broken system where correctly *installing* the microcode was one of several steps needed to get the system running smoothly enough for the wireless to work as expected. Thank you so much for your kind words.

Comment: No, thank you for all your hard work and dedication and also this clarification. ~90% of the wireless issues I had dealt with in recent years were solved - indirectly - by you. And I also got the information about the recommended wireless encryption settings from your posts, answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS to get your Wi-Fi working.

Microcode is irrelevant.